# copy a file from inside of a directory in a filelist

Tags: ant

I have a `filelist` that contains a list of directories. I need to iterate through that `filelist` and get a file from each directory and copy it to another location.

I was attempting to use `filelist` in combination with `foreach`, but `foreach` does not support `filelist`. Is there any other way of doing this in ANT?

---

**My attempt with `for`.**

This fails at the `<copy>` task saying that it cannot find a directory. The directory it is looking for is `${basedir}/bin/` instead of the directory that is first listed in the `filelist` it is given. I am assuming it is because it is not reading my `filelist` correctly. My `foreach` version gives the same error.

```
    <for 
        list="devBuild"
        delimiter=","
        param="dirName"
        trim="true">
        <sequential>
            <copy
                todir="./apks/"
                failonerror="true"
                verbose="true">
                <fileset dir="@{dirName}/../bin/">
                    <include name="*/*.apk"/>
                </fileset>
            </copy>
        </sequential>
    </for>
```

---

**Partially Working**

Right now, the `for` loop is working... kinda. The way i want it to work is shown directly below. However, this fails saying the `devBuild` reference can not be found. However, that `filelist` is created earlier in a different `target` and is created with that reference. Why can i not use that reference ID in a different target?

```
    <for
        delimiter=","
        param="dirName"
        trim="true">
        <path>
            <filelist
                refid="devBuild"></filelist>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <echo>@{dirName}</echo>
            <copy
                todir="./apks/"
                failonerror="true"
                verbose="true">
                <fileset dir="@{dirName}/../bin/">
                    <include name="*/*.apk"/>
                </fileset>
            </copy>
        </sequential>
    </for>
```

The following way does work, but i would like to use the reference ID instead of creating the `filelist` again.

```
    <for
        delimiter=","
        param="dirName"
        trim="true">
        <path>
            <filelist
                id="devBuild"
                dir="${basedir}"
                files="${build1},${build2},${build3},${build4}"
            />
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <echo>@{dirName}</echo>
            <copy
                todir="./apks/"
                failonerror="true"
                verbose="true">
                <fileset dir="@{dirName}/../bin/">
                    <include name="*/*.apk"/>
                </fileset>
            </copy>
        </sequential>
    </for>
```

Comment: Yes and with no resolution. Details are posted in op.

Comment: I had some success, but still having trouble getting a `filelist` reference ID to work.

Comment: Also changed `*/*.apk` to `**/*.apk`. This fixed an unrelated problem.

Comment: I figured out the problem. When i am making my call to this other `target` i was not setting the flag for `inheritrefs`. This needs to be true so the other `target` will get the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When i am making my call to this other `target` i was not setting the flag for `inheritrefs`. This needs to be true so the other `target` will get the references.